# Apache mod_rewrite changes the REAL server port output in a PHP script

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, port

I noticed that when using mod_rewrite, PHP returns server_port 80 even if apache is on port 8080.

i.e I have this url: http://myvirtualhost.8080/index.php and this PHP snippet:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; ?>
```

In .htaccess I have this simple rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     ^/?$            index.php           [NC,L]
```

With mod_rewrite on, output is "80" (wrong)

With mod_rewrite off, output is "8080" (correct)

Is it normal? Anysimple solutions for this?
The fact is that i need to check the REAL server port to use in a conditional PHP script, something like:

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
do something
} else {
do something else
}
?>
```

and of course this is actually not possible since with mod_rewrite on the SERVER_PORT is always 80. I prefer not to mess with .htaccess file, so a PHP script solution would be great...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You need to set "UseCanonicalPhysicalPort"

```
UseCanonicalPhysicalPort on
```

this will ensure that rewrite rule will rewrite the url with the same port as the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the server port as well, by adding a colon and the port number, or the SERVER_PORT variable: `www.example.com:%{SERVER_PORT}`.  Check the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#canonicalhost).

Comment: I'd really like to avoid hardcode the server name... is there a solution that doe not involve it? So far I found a solution on SitePoint forum: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=518318

Comment: The answer is in the same paragraph of the apache documentation: use `%{HTTP_HOST}`.